# Gradle Compilation Error in React Native App

Tags: gradle, buildconfig

I encountered compilation errors in my React Native project after updating to version "0.72.7". The errors include "cannot find symbol" for symbols such as PackageList and BuildConfig. Despite updating and performing actions like cleaning the build and reinstalling dependencies, the issues persist.

Steps Taken:

- Updated React Native to version "0.72.7".
- Executed ./gradlew clean for a clean build.
- Ran npm install to update project dependencies.

How to resolve these specific errors or related to the recent React Native version update.